# How to convert a uint8_t array into a string?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, hex, uint8t

I've a function that can convert an hexadecimal string (ex. "02AFA1253...ecc.") into an uint8_t array. I would need to do the opposite, which is to convert the uint8_t array to a string of hexadecimal characters. How to do it? Here is the code of the function that converts hex string to uint8_t array: Thank you everybody for your help!

```
size_t convert_hex(uint8_t *dest, size_t count, const char *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    int value;
    for (i = 0; i < count && sscanf(src + i * 2, "%2x", &value) == 1; i++) {
        dest[i] = value;
    }
    return i;
    }
```

Comment: Either a simple lookup table piecing two nibbles into a pair of hex digit chars, or if performance is zero concern, creative use of `sprintf`. Either will get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the opposite, so do the opposite.

```c
size_t convert_hex_inv(char *dest, size_t count, const uint8_t *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count && sprintf(dest + i * 2, "%02X", src[i]) == 2; i++);
    return i;
}
```

Note that the buffer pointed at by `dest` has to be at least `count * 2 + 1` elements. Don't forget the `+1` for terminating null-character.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. How can I print this array? I'm trying with printf("*********** %c\n", hex_array[0]);, but a strange symbol appears in the terminal. Whit  %s I've segmentation fault.

Comment: @WonderWhy [This code should work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J7LlW20yUhS0P5CH). What is `hex_array`?